# iCalendar script is rendering as html in outlook

Tags: php, email, outlook, cakephp-2.0, icalendar

New to Calendar script, Below is my iCalendar script which is valid when checked in [Icalendar](https://icalendar.org/validator.html) and Gmail app perfectly detects it.But issue is with Outlook and apple default mail app where it will render as HTML in the mail body.

The script is generated in CakePHP 2.X and sent as an email.

```
$message = "BEGIN:VCALENDAR\n";
$message .= "PRODID:-//My//Prod MIMEDIR//EN\n";
$message .= "VERSION:2.0\n";
$message .= "METHOD:PUBLISH\n";
$message .= "BEGIN:VEVENT\n";
$message .= 'ORGANIZER;CN="Test":test@example.com'."\n";
$message .= "UID:20190530T180000-456543\n";
$message .= "DTEND:20190530T190000Z\n";
$message .= "DTSTAMP:".date('Ymd').'T'.date("His")."\n";
$message .= "DTSTART:20190530T180000Z\n";
$message .= "SUMMARY;LANGUAGE=en-us:Event Description\n";
$message .= "DESCRIPTION:Test DESCRIPTION\n";
$message .= "END:VEVENT\n";
$message .= "END:VCALENDAR\n";

$Email = new CakeEmail();
$Email->from(INFO_EMAIL)
->to('test@outlook.com')
->setHeaders(array("Content-Type" => "text/calendar; method=PUBLISH; charset=UTF-8","Content-Disposition" => "inline; filename=filename.ics"))
->subject('Subject')
->send($message);
echo "Script";
exit;
```

Apologies, please redirect me if the question is repeated. Any help here will be appreciated.
[image]

Comment: What is the resulting mailbody that is sent?

Comment: Markus, Have updated the question with screenshot of the output.

Comment: What I actually meant was the source code of the message, i.e. the content of `$Email` right after the subject was added in `->subject('Subject')`

Comment: This Answer helped me for content-type, Now its visible in outlook as attachment and outlook [Web] is providing preview for the same. Where as outlook android mobile app still doesn't show attached .ics file.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21812438/outlook-fails-to-recognize-an-ics-message